# Shell script error on unix: Unsatisfied code symbol 'libintl_bindtextdomain' in load module '/bin/bash'

Tags: bash, unix

I have created an automated script to format the results for a run saved in a text file and then convert and send it as HTML.

I'm running this shell script on a unix server where its giving me below error:

```
asapu@abcde - E2(CCS 7.0) ASAP Server $ original_htmlcreate.sh
/usr/lib/hpux32/dld.so: Unsatisfied code symbol 'libintl_bindtextdomain' in load module '/bin/bash'.
Killed
```

Comment: Can you execute `/bin/bash` successfully without invoking a script?

Comment: As in, how to execute without invoking any script?

Comment: I'm asking if `bash` is actually correctly installed. What is the result of `/bin/bash` by itself on the command line? And what is the result of `echo $SHLIB_PATH`?